# BUSCARV (VLOOKUP) search at sheet 1 or 2 or 3 depends a cell

Tags: excel

I have 7 tables at 7 different sheets
All them have same format (in fact are inventory at different camps)

I want that at main spreadsheet for each item search at its respective spreadsheet
per example:

Camp
Pedernal

Then VLOOKUP search within the spreadsheet called Pedernal

```
=BUSCARV(A131;Pedernal!A:I;3;0)
```

Then at that formula, spreadsheet name depends of other cell

PD: Spanish version, then here function is BUSCARV

Comment: you would use INDIRECT: `=VLOOKUP(A131;INDIRECT("'"&A1"'!A:I");3;0)` where A1 has the sheet name.

Comment: LOL, thanks. I was near, but not SO NEAR. I experimented with =VLOOKUP(A131;INDIRECT(A1!A:I");3;0) but no worked

Comment: Sorry, excel no accept such formula

Comment: sorry missing a `&`: `=VLOOKUP(A131;INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A:I");3;0)`